# How to convert paths into shape in photoshop cs6

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, path

I drew paths thinking i was drawing a shape but later realized it is only a path. Now i could create a temporary shape like a box and paste this in and delete the box path. But just as there is a option to convert path to selection, is there an option to convert the selected path into shape?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Select the *Pen tool*.

Ensure the Pen tool's dropdown menu in the Options bar is set to "Path".

Click the *Shape* button in the Options bar, found to the right of the *Pen tool* dropdown menu.

Press that and presto :p

[image: Photoshop CS6 Pen tool Options bar settings screenshot]

Comment: This actually works much better than the others.  Not sure what the downvote was for on this answer.

Comment: Perfect and simple solution... ^^ what he said! Upvoted.

Comment: This does not work with paths that are already drawn, as asked in the question.

Comment: It works with paths that are already drawn, what are you talking about? Use the path tab in the layers window or go window -> paths.

Comment: Ben's answer addresses paths that are already drawn.

Comment: This does work for shapes that are already drawn. There is the dropdown selector for new paths, yes, but the three buttons to the right ("Selection...", "Mask", "Shape") operate on the currently selected path.

Comment: To see the `shape` button the dropdown box needs to be on `path`, not `shape`

Answer (score 14):

When created vector path just create a solid filled layer in adjustment layers.

[image]

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3vRZq6f7Rvo

Comment: When I add a Shape using the method in your answer, the **Properties** tab does not show the **Appearance** section where the stroke color/width etc can be customized. Do you know how to get the Appearance controls to ...appear? *(This behavior is different compared to when adding a Shape using the Rectangle tool or Polygon tool, for example.)*

Comment: Workaround found: The **Fill** and **Stroke** options are available up in the **Control Panel**, as long as the **Pen** tool is active. *(Although the inconsistency of some Shape Layers providing these controls under the **Properties** tab's **Appearance** section and others not - depending on how the shape was created - still strikes me as odd.)*

Answer (score 8):

Not sure how it is in **CS6**, but try this:

1. Go to `Window > Paths`
2. Select the path you created
3. Go to `Edit > Define Custom Shape...`
4. Name it if you'd like
5. Go to your `Custom Shapes` tool (cycle through pressing <kbd>U</kbd>)
6. With the `Custom Shapes` tool selected, you will see the `Custom Shapes Picker` icon
7. Click the arrow to open the `Custom Shapes Picker`.

[image]

Your new custom shape will be at the bottom.

Answer (score 6):

After having created a path, deselect it and switch to the pen tool. Draw a single point outside the canvas (for the sake of easily finding it later). This creates an [almost] empty shape shape layer. Switch back to your path, hold CTRL and marquee select every point in the path, then copy the path information with CTRL+C. Switch back to the shape layer, hold CTRL and select the single point you made, then paste the path information with CTRL+V. Finally delete the single point you created in the first place. Done.

Comment: Hi Ben, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: this trick looks new ill try

Comment: brilliant! and should be the accepted answer

Comment: I don't see how anyone could think that this process is easier than one click of the 'Shape' button...

Answer (score 3):

If you created a path and want to turn it into a shape, make sure the path is selected, then go to LAYER > NEW FILL LAYER > SOLID COLOR > Name the layer and hit OK. You will now have a shape layer as desired.

Answer (score 2):

Using this method we can create a shape using a path...

[image: these method we can create shape using path.....]

Comment: look at the top answer there is a better way to convert path into shape than saving it permanently into symbol than dragging it to stage and deleting the path already there.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Adobe CS6 the fastest to do that is by using the pen tool and you can find above is the button `shape` click on it and it will convert your path to shape.

If you like to return the shape into path just go to windows->paths 
and delete `shape 1 shape path` similar name and it will go back to path.

Comment: Please add a screenshot to show where the tool and the named buttons can be found.  Welcome to GD.SE!

Answer (score 0):

All those Define custome shape... or fill layer are not your final answer.
Just do this:

1. Open path panel to make sure your path is in there.
2. Create another shape (not a path).
3. Click your path created before in path panel, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.
4. Click your new shape in layer panel, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.
5. Press <kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> until see black mouse to select 'path select tool'.
6. Your shape now has 2 paths, click the path you want to delete and press <kbd>Delete</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

**Very** old question, resolved with more recent versions of Photoshop...

---

## In Photoshop CC...

Use the **Path Selection Tool** (Black arrow)... select *any* path.

- Choose `Layer > New Fill Layer > Solid Color` (You can change this later, no worries)
- Click `OK` in the new Layer dialog window
- Click `OK` in the Color Picker window

Result is a shape layer with your path as the shape.

[image]

You can then merely delete the `Work Path` in the **Paths Panel** if you want - it's not imperative you do though.

(This *may* work in CS6 as well)