# Photoshop CS6 Scripting - How transform Work Path into Shape?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, photoshop-scripting

I have a Work Path I'd like to convert into a shape layer. It can be done through the UI by pressing the "Shape" button at the Pen tool menu as shown [in this answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/28019/97331).

How do I do that through scripting?

I used the Script Listener to capture it, but the output doesn't contain the converting function:

```
// =======================================================
// Select Work Path
var idslct = charIDToTypeID( "slct" );
    var desc6704 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var idnull = charIDToTypeID( "null" );
        var ref4022 = new ActionReference();
        var idPath = charIDToTypeID( "Path" );
        var idWrPt = charIDToTypeID( "WrPt" );
        ref4022.putProperty( idPath, idWrPt );
    desc6704.putReference( idnull, ref4022 );
executeAction( idslct, desc6704, DialogModes.NO );

// =======================================================
// Select Pen Tool
var idslct = charIDToTypeID( "slct" );
    var desc6705 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var idnull = charIDToTypeID( "null" );
        var ref4023 = new ActionReference();
        var idpenTool = stringIDToTypeID( "penTool" );
        ref4023.putClass( idpenTool );
    desc6705.putReference( idnull, ref4023 );
    var iddontRecord = stringIDToTypeID( "dontRecord" );
    desc6705.putBoolean( iddontRecord, true );
    var idforceNotify = stringIDToTypeID( "forceNotify" );
    desc6705.putBoolean( idforceNotify, true );
executeAction( idslct, desc6705, DialogModes.NO );

// The End.
```

I tried to cheat and record it as an Action to trigger through the script, but unsurprisingly transforming Paths into Shapes doesn't get recorded as Action either.

Is there a way to capture and reproduce this action programmatically at all without creating junk custom shapes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a `Create Solid Fill` layer command: when you have path selected it'll create a shape layer based on the active path. Here's the code:

```
function createShapeLayer(color) {
    if (color == undefined) var color = app.foregroundColor;

    var desc32 = new ActionDescriptor();
        var ref2 = new ActionReference();
        ref2.putClass( sTID('contentLayer') );
    desc32.putReference( cTID('null'), ref2 );
        var desc33 = new ActionDescriptor();
            var desc34 = new ActionDescriptor();
                var desc35 = new ActionDescriptor();
                desc35.putDouble( cTID('Rd  '), color.rgb.red );
                desc35.putDouble( cTID('Grn '), color.rgb.green );
                desc35.putDouble( cTID('Bl  '), color.rgb.blue );
            desc34.putObject( cTID('Clr '), cTID('RGBC'), desc35 );
        desc33.putObject( cTID('Type'), sTID('solidColorLayer'), desc34 );
    desc32.putObject( cTID('Usng'), sTID('contentLayer'), desc33 );
    executeAction( cTID('Mk  '), desc32, DialogModes.NO );

    function cTID(s) { return app.charIDToTypeID(s); };
    function sTID(s) { return app.stringIDToTypeID(s); };
}; // end of createShapeLayer()
```

This function will use foreground color for the shape by default or a `SolidColor` passed as an argument.

Comment: I ended doing something similar, but referencing the work path bounds in the shape layer desc because I had no idea it'd use the active path bounds by default. Thank you, that's way more elegant than my code!